ADB command expanded notifications
I am inquiring about potential methods to execute specific ADB commands that would facilitate the automatic expansion or collapse of all incoming notifications in the status bar, thereby eliminating the need to manually expand each notification, particularly in the context of grouped notifications. Your guidance and insights on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
adb shell settings put global heads_up_n otifications_enabled 1 

This command didn't help.
